# Is it possible to Filter all the data in a map using Experience builder filter widget?

Tags: filter, arcgis-experience-builder, enterprise

I am using Experience builder on ArcGIS Enterprise (10.9.1 I believe). I'm making a dashboard and I am trying to filter all the data based on date.

When making dashboards in the Dashboard application this is possible and pretty simple as you could set up a filter and it would filter all the layers as long as they had a date field.

This doesn't seem to be possible in Experience builder and you would have to set up a date filter for every layer individually.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The filter widget does not currently support filtering multiple layers simultaneously.

Your available solutions would be to use the Query widget and set up message actions based on the queries, or enable time on all of your data sets and implement a time slider element.